Nightingale rose chart visualization overlapped
I use the following code to draw nightingale rose chart:
mydata = pd.DataFrame(dict(model=["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"], auc_roc=[99.7, 80.2, 85.3, 87.9, 89.2, 88.6, 91.0, 96.6]))

n_row = mydata.shape[0]
angle = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 2*np.pi/n_row)
radius = np.array(mydata.auc_roc)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4), dpi=180)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)

ax.set_theta_offset(np.pi/2-np.pi/n_row)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.set_rlabel_position(360-180/n_row)

# colors = ['#FFB300', '#803E75', '#FF6800', '#A6BDD7', '#C10020', '#CEA262', '#817066', '#007D34']
cmap=cm.get_cmap('Reds', n_col)
all_color=[colors.rgb2hex(cmap(i)[:8]) for i in range(cmap.N)]
bars = ax.bar(angle, radius, color=all_color, edgecolor="k", width=0.90, alpha=0.9)

for bar in bars:
    height = bar.get_height()
    ax.text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2.0, height, f'{height:.1f}', ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.xticks(angle, labels=mydata.model, size=8)
plt.ylim(0, 105)
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 100, 10))

plt.grid(which='major', axis="x", linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='gray', alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(which='major', axis="y", linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='gray', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()

This figure is shown as:
enter image description here
However, each category has the overlapped content in the figure. How to solve it?

The angle is not set right, the correct code is as the following:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

categories = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
values = [0.997, 0.802, 0.853, 0.879, 0.892, 0.886, 0.910, 0.966]

# Calculate the angle and width of each category
total = sum(values)
angles = [2 * np.pi * (i / len(categories)) for i in range(len(categories))]
widths = [2 * np.pi / len(categories)] * len(categories)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6), dpi=180)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

# Plot each category as a bar
bars = ax.bar(angles, values, width=widths, bottom=0.0, color='skyblue', edgecolor="k", alpha=0.7)

# Customize the plot
ax.set_xticks(angles)
ax.set_xticklabels(categories)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.1)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.2))


# Add labels to each bar
for i, bar in enumerate(bars):
    angle = angles[i]
    width = bar.get_width()
    height = bar.get_height()
    x = bar.get_x() + width/2.0
    y = height
    ax.text(x, y, f'{height:.3f}', ha='center', va='bottom')

# Add a title
plt.title('Nightingale Rose Chart')
plt.grid(which='major', axis='x', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='gray', alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(which='major', axis='y', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='gray', alpha=0.5)

# Display the chart
plt.show()

The figure is shown as: 
